# How sign my app as "system application" android

Tags: android, access-point

I've an application that writes some APN settings. Since from Android 4.0 this operation is no more allowed, but for system applications, my question is:

Is there any way to sign my application as "System app", so it can be installed on no-rooted devices and get access to APN settings?

Answer (score 0):

On non-rooted devices above IceCreamSandwich, you can't.
(Unless you have the signature key which was used to sign the operating system, i.e. the hardware manufacturer's key or the one of your ROM)

> signatureOrSystem permissions are available to applications signed with the same key used to sign the device operating system.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24227