# What are the specific keys(platform.x509.pem and platform.pk8) used in Lenovo TAB A7-30HC

Tags: android

What are the specific keys(platform.x509.pem and platform.pk8) used in Lenovo TAB A7-30HC, Im unable to used the system functions in which using these keys :https://github.com/android/platform_build/tree/master/target/product/security,

But some tabs do work with signing using these keys.

I tried:

Moving my system-signedapp to system/app and system/priv-app in lenovo tab specifically Kitkat, but i cant access system functions, It didnt gave me a system access.

How do I mitigate this?

Ive used these procedure to sign it

[Signing my android application as system app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586255/signing-my-android-application-as-system-app/37586790#37586790)

Comment: have you try to install sign apk with adb? just as "./adb install any.apk"

Comment: im building a release version and signed it with signapk using platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem , but i dont understand it wont work on lenovo but would work on some tab that doesnt have brands.

Comment: it may happens due to different key used by particular OEM apart from you using, try to install you apk from adb and let me know what its output if its "success" then there is no issue with key but if key is not matched then adb will report you something like "different signature".

Comment: @AparAmin where do i check if it is different signature? may i know what code/script i should use?

Comment: if you talking from developer perspective i already told you, you can check from "adb install <your.apk>" if you able to install it successfully then its not an issue of key, if you don't able to install it then there is several issue one of them might be possible difference in version of OS as well build number.

Comment: i am able to install it successfully thru adb command, what else should i check please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120673/discussion-between-apar-amin-and-david).