# How to create System Apps in android using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Guys I want to know how I can create system application for Android (that should be unremovable) and I want to know if there is a solution to generate it from android studio application?

Comment: this might help https://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.com/2017/01/make-app-as-system-app-in-android.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signing my android application as system app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586255/signing-my-android-application-as-system-app)

Comment: no, I just want to run my app as system app

Comment: That question explains how to do so.